# How to String matchAll in Reason?

Tags: reason, bucklescript, rescript

I'm trying to replicate what I would do in javascript with `matchAll()`

```js
  const names = [
    ...withoutSlashes.matchAll(/(?<=Pos\. \d+ \- )(.*?)(?=","Importe)/g),
  ];
```

I see Reason has `Js.String.match` but I can't find the matchAll. I guess it's because matchAll is a newer ecmascript.

Any hint on which would be a good way to do a performant matchAll? or is there a specific Reason feature that I'm missing?

Comment: MatchAll is basically syntactic sugar (easier to understand), you can just call match repeatedly.

Comment: BTW: You don't need to create any groups in your regex: replace '(.*?)' with just '.*?'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind to it yourself. The biggest problem with it is that it returns an iterator, which we also don't have bindings for. But we can use `Js.Array.array_like('a)` and then convert it to an array using `Js.Array.from`:

```ml
[@bs.send.pipe: string]
external matchAll: Js.Re.t => Js.Array.array_like(array(string)) = "matchAll";

let matches = "abc" |> matchAll([%re "/[a-c]/g"]) |> Js.Array.from;
```

Comment: We do have `Iterator` bindings in bs-fetch (and transitively in bs-webapi) now ... if adding those is not desirable then the bindings can be copied: https://github.com/reasonml-community/bs-fetch/blob/master/src/Fetch__Iterator.mli and https://github.com/reasonml-community/bs-fetch/blob/master/src/Fetch__Iterator.ml

Answer (score 3):

Based on the accepted answer I wanted to add a version that is following ReScript conventions. `[@bs.send.pipe]` is discouraged, and the ReScript language officially recommends the pipe-first operator (`->` instead of `|>`).

like this:

```
[@bs.send]
external matchAll: (string, Js.Re.t) => Js.Array.array_like(array(string)) =
  "matchAll";

let matches: array(string) =
  matchAll("abc", [%re "/[a-c]/g"])->Js.Array.from;
```

Comment: On the @ryyppy example, compiler says the type on your example should be `array(array(string)`.